# Python - Selenium: Unable to locate element loaded within a frame

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, icloud

I'm trying to automate the process of uploading contacts to my [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/contacts/) account.
But, I'm unable to get Selenium to find the **Show Actions Menu** button which is located at the bottom left.

I know the button is loaded within a frame, so I switched to the frame but still couldn't get it to find the button.

Here's the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_driver_path = '/chromedriver.exe'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=NetworkService")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-csp")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)
url = "https://www.icloud.com/contacts/"
with driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(10)
    #wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sc1737"]')))
    driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id('contacts'))
    #Tried locating the frame by xpath too, but didn't work
    #driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contacts"]'))
    driver.find_element_by_id('sc1737').click()
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Extra steps I tried as debugging:

Using pdb, I tried locating an element within the frame (the whole left side of the iCloud page) before switching to the frame, but I got the same error:
`Unable to locate element`

So I tried switching to the frame, then locate the same element, and it was found with no problem, which proves that switching to the frame worked.

Finally, tried to locate the button I'm after, but still gave me the same error.

Comment: As an aside, are you on macOS?

Comment: @AMC sorry, forgot to specify, Windows actually.

Comment: @KiDo I don't find any **Show Action Menu** button on https://www.icloud.com/contacts/ page